# Powershell - Compare CSV file to AD and get an Output File

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with one column called employeeID which has all the employee ID's. I need to compare this file to Active Directory and get an output file showing 3 columns - samaccountname, distinguisedName, cn.
I'm new to Powershell and have the following:

```
$names = Import-CSV -Path "C:\temp\vendors.csv"
$outFile = "C:\temp\RESULT-Status.csv"

if (Test-Path $outFile) {Remove-Item $outFile -Force}
Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value "cn,samaccountname,distinguisedName"

foreach ($name in $names)
{
    $result = Get-ADUser -filter "CN -eq '$($name.cn)' -and employeeID -eq '$($name.employeeID)'" -Properties * | select enabled,samaccountname,cn,distinguisedName
    Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value "$($result.displayname),$($result.samaccountname),$($result.enabled),$($result.distinguisedName)"
}
```

Getting errors...any help appreciated. I might be looking at this completely wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the errors you are getting?

Comment: You misspelled `distinguishedName`